# How can one measure the cpu time of a thread in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, timing

The end goal is to time the execution of individual parallel functions.   If my understanding of clock() is correct, this measures elapsed time rather than cpu time.

I am looking for some alternative to:

```
clock_t t;
t=clock();
function();
clock_t elapsed_time = t - clock();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [tour] and also read [ask] to get better answers for your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring CPU time in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167685/measuring-cpu-time-in-c)

Comment: Just simple quick search returns [How can I measure CPU time and wall clock time on both Linux/Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432502/how-can-i-measure-cpu-time-and-wall-clock-time-on-both-linux-windows)

Comment: You can use the chrono's [high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) and modify that example so that it casts to milliseconds.

Comment: You can't in C++ really. You'll have to resort OS APIs for that usually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I measure CPU time and wall clock time on both Linux/Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432502/how-can-i-measure-cpu-time-and-wall-clock-time-on-both-linux-windows)